# Evaluating $ \prod_{i=1}^n 3^{2^i} + \sum_{i=1}^n 3^{2^{i+1}-1} \prod_{j=i+1}^n 3^{2^j}$

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I'm working on difference equations and got stuck on the algebra with this one:

$$ u_n = \prod_{i=1}^n 3^{2^i} + \sum_{i=1}^n 3^{2^{i+1}-1} \prod_{j=i+1}^n 3^{2^j}$$

I need to simplify this to just a function of n. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ah yes thanks! fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for immediate reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We  obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\prod_{i=1}^n3^{2^i}}&\color{blue}{+\sum_{i=1}^n3^{2^{i+1}-1}\prod_{j=i+1}^n3^{2^j}}\\
> &=3^{2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^n}+\sum_{i=1}^n3^{2^{i+1}-1}\cdot 3^{2^{i+1}+2^{i+2}+\cdots+2^{n}}\\
> &=3^{2\left(2^n-1\right)}+\sum_{i=1}^n3^{2^{i+1}-1}\cdot 3^{2^{i+1}\left(2^{n-i}-1\right)}\\
> &=3^{2\left(2^n-1\right)}+\sum_{i=1}^n3^{2^{i+1}-1}\cdot 3^{2^{n+1}-2^{i+1}}\\
> &=3^{2\left(2^n-1\right)}+3^{2^{n+1}-1}\sum_{i=1}^n1\\
> &=\frac{1}{9}3^{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{3}3^{2^{n+1}}n\\
> &\color{blue}{=(3n+1)3^{2^{n+1}-2}}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, so I got the second line from the bottom based on the comments below, but was missing the n multiplier. How does that come about?

Comment: @Krog: I've added a line which might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may use that
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n 3^{2^i}=3^{\large \sum_{i=1}^n2^i},\qquad \prod_{j=i+1}^n 3^{2^j}=3^{\large \sum_{j=i+1}^n2^j}.
$$ Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
&\overbrace{\ \prod_{i=1}^n3^{2^i}\ }^{3^{2^{n+1}-2}}+\sum_{i=1}^n3^{2^{i+1}-1}\overbrace{\ \prod_{j=i+1}^n3^{2^j}\ }^{3^{2^{n+1}-2^{i+1}}}\\
&=3^{2^{n+1}-2}+\sum_{i=1}^n3\cdot3^{2^{n+1}-2}\\[6pt]
&=(3n+1)3^{2^{n+1}-2}
\end{align}
$$